# What's proper English for 'experimentee'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, is-it-a-word

What is the English word / phrase for things / persons that are experimented on? I think of experimentee but I believe there may be more common words.

Comment: You're probably thinking of the ***subject** [of the experiment]*. If so, I think that's General Reference.

Comment: Perhaps the _subject_?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Subject* (or *research subject*) may be the most common one.  *Guinea pig* for unwitting subjects, or subjects unethically treated.

In psychological experiments a *confederate* is a study assistant that interacts with the subject but whom the subject believes is not involved in any such capacity.  Typically subjects are led to believe that confederates are also subjects.

Comment: Participant is being pushed as a replacement for subject.

Comment: see the APA on subjects versus participants: http://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/subjects-and-participants.aspx

Comment: @emory Some reference would be nice.

Comment: Note that "guinea pig" is also permitted when the subjects are in fact guinea pigs.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you conduct your experiment on is its *subject*.

Comment: I've written a few research protocols for human *subjects*.

Comment: *Thing*, or as in the present case, a *person* or any *animate object*.

Answer (score 1):

[**Human subjects**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Subject)

"The United States Department of Health and Human Services (DHHS) defines a **human research subject** as a living individual about whom a research investigator (whether a professional or a student) obtains data through 1) intervention or interaction with the individual, or 2) identifiable private information (32 CFR 219.102.f). ([Lim,1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Subject#cite_note-utexas-1))"